# Keep subview aligned to top on .NET MAUI ScrollView [iOS issue]

Tags: c#, ios, .net, maui

I have a VerticalStackLayout inside a ScrollView. Some items inside the VerticalStackLayout are shown/hidden dynamically at runtime. I noticed that, on iOS, the VerticalStackLayout is shifted down (it's Y position changes) inside the ScrollView when it has been scrolled and the visibility status of one of it's children changes after that. I think this should not happen at all. On Android it behaves as expected (the VerticalStackLayout keeps at top).

Steps to reproduce:

- Create a new .NET MAUI App and change the XAML markup and code behind to the following:

XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="ScrollViewBug.MainPage">

    <ScrollView x:Name="MyScroll">
        <VerticalStackLayout
            x:Name="MyStack"
            Spacing="25"
            Padding="30,0"
            VerticalOptions="Start"
            BackgroundColor="AliceBlue">

            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Cute dot net bot waving hi to you!"
                HeightRequest="200"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1"
                FontSize="32"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to .NET Multi-platform App UI"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I"
                FontSize="18"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me"
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" />

            <Grid x:Name="MyGrid" HeightRequest="600" BackgroundColor="Yellow" IsVisible="False"/>

        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```cs
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace ScrollViewBug;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    int count = 0;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MyStack.PropertyChanged += StackPropertyChanged;
    }

    private void StackPropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PropertyName == "Y")
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"This Stack Y: {Math.Floor(MyStack.Y)}");
        }        
    }

    private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        count++;

        if (count == 1)
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
        else
            CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

        MyGrid.IsVisible = !MyGrid.IsVisible;

        SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make a custom handler that keeps the ScrollView sub-views at place (Y=0) when the sub-view ContentSize changes?

I've tried to intercept changes on the ScrollView ContentSize using a custom handler, and replace the subview frame (changing it's Y position to zero), but it had no effect.

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac 17.6.6 (build 408) + .NET 8 RC2.

Comment: Do you face the same issue with .Net7

Comment: Actually, not tested. I'm migrating a Xamarin.Forms app to .NET MAUI, and the requirement is that it goes directly to .NET 8 (which I hope will be available soon). Thus, I'm concentrating efforts on making it run on RC2.

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand why a component inside a ScrollView should obey  any alignment property. I "think" if you are using a ScrollView, it's because your content is greater than the view (greater than the ScrollView frame). So... any alignment property like Start or End makes no sense (to me) and should just be ignored by the view.

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is that you're facing. Can you show a screenshot of what's happening? There are a few bugs related to the ScrollView on iOS, such as this one: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15374

Comment: I tested you code but can't reproduce your problem. The Y property didn't changed but the Height property did. I tested on .net 7 and .net 8. The results on android and ios were same.

Comment: I've posted a video [here](https://youtube.com/shorts/zIPuR1jBdqs?feature=share) showing the behavior I'm trying to patch. More details on the video description. Tested on iPhone 15 Pro Max iOS 17 (simulator).

Comment: Just to clarify: on my example, you must tap the button to show the yellow spacer; then you have to scroll the screen to the end, and tap the button again. You'll notice that the VerticalStackLayout will be displaced (shifted down) an arbitrary amount of space. The displacement will depend on how much the screen is scrolled at the moment of the second tap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem now. And the cause is the ScrollView doesn't recalculate new size on iOS when the child's visibility is changed to false.

You can use the following code to resolve it:

In the MauiProgram.cs:

```
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });
#if IOS
        ScrollViewHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("ContentSize", (handler, view) =>
        {
            handler.PlatformView.UpdateContentSize(handler.VirtualView.ContentSize);
            handler.PlatformArrange(handler.PlatformView.Frame.ToRectangle());
        });
#endif
        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this didn't fix it for me. I did a simple solution which is add TranslationY to the first child of the scrollview which is bound to the Y value of that same first child so that when Y changes (we don't know why) the same value is added in negative to TranslationY. This in turn makes Y zero again fixing the issue.
The code used for this is the follows:

1. First add static resource for [MathsExpressionConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/math-expression-converter)
2. Then add binding for TranslationY so that it references Y property of the same view under ScrollView

Here is the sample code for this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:Class="TestMaui.MainPage">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <toolkit:MathExpressionConverter x:Key="MathExpressionConverter" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ScrollView>
        <!--Any child like VerticalStackLayout-->
        <VerticalStackLayout TranslationY="{Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Y, Converter={StaticResource MathExpressionConverter}, ConverterParameter='-1*x' }" >
           <!--Any content-->
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

I hope that helps someone out there.

Comment: Indeed, I was using this little hack too. I've added this issue to MAUI GitHub repo, and they told a fix will come up on GA, at .NET Conf 2023. Link to the issue: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18513

Comment: Great, sorry I didn't notice that you included the suggestion. I just made a simpler way to implement it but thanks for brining the original issue. I hope it will be fixed in the GA of .net 8 coming tomorrow .